# Clustered search results for .net app on Win '03 / '08

Tags: asp.net, search, lucene

i'm building a .net app using ASP.net 3.5 on win '03 or '08 (not sure yet) using SQL Server 2008.

A major part of the app is building a powerful search function which has to cluster search results similar to this site.

e.g. search for blindness and you see a cluster of results for blindness but also for visually impaired, eye etc.

I'm looking for recommendations for approaches working with off the shelf indexing technology on windows server 2003/2008 (preferably open source).

I've looked at:

Carrot2 - http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search

which looks very powerful but seems to rely on other indexes like Lucene and Solr.

Has anyone any experience working with these technologies on a windows platform? Do they play nicely with IIS?

Many thanks for any assistance.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

There is a c# port of lucene (called lucene.NET) which works perfectly on windows (as you would expect, since it's using .NET).

Comment: Solr offers carrot2 clustering and a number of things out-of-the-box, and is easily integrable from ASP.NET using SolrNet. why bother with Lucene.net? Querying Lucene from asp.net can be a pain, if you consider large indexes and memory management etc.

Comment: @Mikos: some people don't want to maintain a Java stack in addition to their .NET stuff. But you are right, in many cases it's easier to run Solr and acesss that with SolrNet rather than maintain Lucene.NET